# Update element by "_id" in mongodb through Node server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongo-shell

In MongoDB, I send one query and it's working, but when I try to send it through node js it is not working.

Working code(mongo shell):

```
db.lists.updateOne(
{ "items._id": ObjectId("6309d49116a56eb8cf296b21") },
{ $set: { "items.$.compleated": true } } );
```

Not Working code(server.js):

```
List.updateOne(
{ "items._id": 'ObjectId("6309d49116a56eb8cf296b21")' },
{ $set: { "items.$.compleated": false } } );
```

Do you have any suggestions related to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I forget the callback, that's all. Code is working.

```
List.updateOne(
{ "items._id": ObjectId("6309d49116a56eb8cf296b21") },
{ $set: { "items.$.compleated": false } },
(err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success");
  }
} );
```

Comment: Also, `collection.updateOne` method returns a _update result_ document - it has details about the update operation, like the `matchedCount` and `modifiedCount`.